# Why in the Student(Student s) can I use the instance variables?

Tags: java, class, private, access-modifiers

So in the constructor `Student(Student s)` why can I use `s.name`?  Usually when we use an object that has private instance variables we need to type `s.getName()` assuming a method is there to access the information. Why in this case can we use `s.name`, `s.score1`, etc.

I assume it is because it is within its own class but I cant wrap my head around why.

```
/** 
 * Manage a student's name and three test scores.
 */
public class Student {
    //Each student object has a name and three test scores
    private String name;             //Student name
    private int test1;               //Score on test 1
    private int test2;               //Score on test 2
    private int test3;               //Score on test 3

    /**
     * Default Constructor
     * Initializes name, test1, test2, and test3 to the default values
     */
    public Student() {
        this("", 0,0,0);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a Student object with the user supplying the name
     * test1, test2, and test3
     */
    public Student(String nm, int t1, int t2, int t3) {
        name = nm;
        test1 = t1;
        test2 = t2;
        test3 = t3;
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a Student object with the user supplying
     * a Student object as the parameter
     */
    public Student(Student s){
        this(s.name = "bill",s.test1,s.test2,s.test3);
    }
```

Comment: It's like you said: `private` means the variable can be accessed within the scope of your own class (and therefore in all nested scopes).

Comment: Someone needs to brush up on security modifiers. :P

Comment: If you couldn't access private variables from the constructor, how could you set the value of a class variable that didn't have a setter?

Comment: To be fair - it's not completely obvious that `private` manes private to the _class_ and not the _object_.

Comment: @Powerlord I think the OP's confusion comes from the fact that a constructor of one instance is referencing "private" data of _another_ instance.

Comment: "Methods, Variables and Constructors that are declared private can only be accessed within the declared class itself." -http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_access_modifiers.htm

Answer (score 2):

A constructor is a member of the class, and thus can access private members, even of other instances of the class. They are private to the *class*, not the *object*.  Private members can also be directly accessed from methods and property accessors.

Answer (score 2):

the keyword `private` in Java means that you have only access to that member if you're working inside the class. Check the following example:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    ...
    public equals(Person other) {
        // You're inside the person class here, therefore you can access
        // Every member of any Person object (no matter if the object is "this" or any other)
        return this.name.equals(other.name)
    }
}
```

I think the best to understand this would be to make it clear to yourself that using any class member is just the same as using it on the object `this`. E.g. if you write:

```
person = "Peter Grand";
```

is just the same as

```
this.person = "Peter Grand";
```

Comment: Do you mean `other.name` instead of `Person.name`?

Comment: Thanks @Holloway. I corrected it!

Answer (score 2):

Because `public`, `private`, and other access modifiers are specified on `class`-level, not in instance (object) level. So in a class, you have access to all the `private` members of all instances of that class; in an inherited class, you have access to all protected members of instances of that class, etc.

That makes sense because setters will definitely need access to the private members: how else can the set the fields of an instance? For constructors it is the same way.

Furthermore note that constructors sometimes are the only members that can set a field: if the field is marked `final`.

Answer (score 1):

`private` means you can access it in your own class but not from outside the class .Since you are accessing `name` from within the `Student` class constructor it works.

Answer (score 1):

The member `name` is declared `private`, which  means the variable can be accessed within the scope of your own class (**and therefore in all nested scopes**).